# How to optimize this query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, filesort

I have these two tables (Moodle 2.8):

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_course` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sortorder` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fullname` varchar(254) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `shortname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `idnumber` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `summary` longtext,
  `summaryformat` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `format` varchar(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'topics',
  `showgrades` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `newsitems` mediumint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `startdate` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `marker` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxbytes` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `legacyfiles` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `showreports` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `visibleold` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `groupmode` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupmodeforce` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `defaultgroupingid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `theme` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timecreated` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timemodified` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `requested` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enablecompletion` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completionnotify` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cacherev` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `calendartype` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_cat_ix` (`category`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_idn_ix` (`idnumber`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_sho_ix` (`shortname`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_sor_ix` (`sortorder`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `mdl_log` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `course` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `module` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cmid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `action` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `info` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mdl_log_coumodact_ix` (`course`,`module`,`action`),
  KEY `mdl_log_tim_ix` (`time`),
  KEY `mdl_log_act_ix` (`action`),
  KEY `mdl_log_usecou_ix` (`userid`,`course`),
  KEY `mdl_log_cmi_ix` (`cmid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this query:

```
SELECT l.id,
       l.userid AS participantid,
       l.course AS courseid,
       l.time,
       l.ip,
       l.action,
       l.info,
       l.module,
       l.url
FROM   mdl_log l
INNER JOIN mdl_course c ON l.course = c.id AND c.category <> 0      
WHERE 
      l.id > [some large id]
      AND
      l.time > [some unix timestamp]
ORDER BY l.id ASC
LIMIT 0,200
```

mdl_log table has over 200 milion records, and I need to export it into file using PHP and not die in intent. The main problem here is that executing this is too slow. The main killer here is the join to the mdl_course table. If I remove it, everything works fast.

Here is the explain:

> ```
> +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
> | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                               | key                  | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra                                                     |
> +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
> |  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | range | PRIMARY,mdl_cour_cat_ix                     | mdl_cour_cat_ix      | 8       | NULL           | 3152 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
> |  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | ref   | PRIMARY,mdl_log_coumodact_ix,mdl_log_tim_ix | mdl_log_coumodact_ix | 8       | xray2qasb.c.id |  618 | Using index condition; Using where                        |
> +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Is there any way to remove usage of temporary and filesort? What do you propose here?

Comment: Try adding an index that contains (`l.time`, `l.course`), since those are the filters your query us using. You **might** consider adding `category` to the `log` table as well; even though it's not normalized, it might improve performance enough to be worth the trouble. You would add `l.category` to the index as well if you went that way.

Comment: you're not using any fields from `mdl_course` in your select.. you might be able to move that to your `where` as an `exists` statement

Comment: It also might be worth the effort to restructure these tables so the text fields that aren't useful for analysis are pushed out to their own table and referenced via an id similarly to the log. This can reduce some of the drag on queries that are more referential in nature. The fallout is that if there are other resources dependent on this structure, they would have to be reworked to support the new structure.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not going to happen. I have to work with structures as they are... I can only add indexes or new tables where needed....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing this query works fast as expected:

```
SELECT l.id,
       l.userid AS participantid,
       l.course AS courseid,
       l.time,
       l.ip,
       l.action,
       l.info,
       l.module,
       l.url
FROM   mdl_log l
WHERE 
      l.id > 123456
      AND
      l.time > 1234
      AND
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mdl_course c WHERE l.course = c.id AND c.category <> 0  )
ORDER BY l.id ASC
LIMIT 0,200
```

Thanks to JamieD77 for his suggestion!

execution plan:

> ```
> +----+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+----------+-------------+
> | id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys           | key     | key_len | ref                | rows     | Extra       |
> +----+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+----------+-------------+
> |  1 | PRIMARY            | l     | range  | PRIMARY,mdl_log_tim_ix  | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL               | 99962199 | Using where |
> |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,mdl_cour_cat_ix | PRIMARY | 8       | xray2qasb.l.course |        1 | Using where |
> +----+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+----------+-------------+
> ```

Comment: can you add the explain plan for this query to your answer post?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the category selection outside the `JOIN`. Here I put it in an `IN()` which the engine will cache on successive runs. I don't have 200M rows to test on, so YMMV.

```
DESCRIBE 

SELECT l.id,
   l.userid AS participantid,
   l.course AS courseid,
   l.time,
   l.ip,
   l.action,
   l.info,
   l.module,
   l.url
FROM   mdl_log l   
WHERE 
  l.id > 1234567890
  AND
  l.time > 1234567890
  AND 
  l.course IN (SELECT c.id FROM mdl_course c WHERE c.category > 0)      
ORDER BY l.id ASC
LIMIT 0,200;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this query is too slow on my database. I stopped it after waiting few minutes.

Comment: How many records in the `mdl_course` table? And, how many of those have `category=0`?

Comment: 6219 records and only one should be with category 0

Comment: try `l.course <> WHATEVER_THAT_COURSE_ID_IS` instead of the `IN()` clause

Comment: OR try `l.course NOT IN (SELECT c.id FROM mdl_course c WHERE c.category = 0)`

Comment: That does not work for me. There could be entries in the log table that are for courses no longer present in the course table. I have to check for both and in general Exists is faster than in for larger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

(In addition to using `EXISTS`...)

```
  l.id > 123456 AND l.time > 1234
```

seems to beg for a 2-dimensional index.

`99962199` -- the table is very big, correct?

Consider `PARTITION BY RANGE` on `mdl_log` on `time`.  But...

- Don't have more than about 50 partitions; other inefficiencies kick in then.
- Partitioning probably won't help `id` and `time` are sorta in lock-step.  Typical case:  `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `time` is approximately the time of the `INSERT`.

If that applies, consider:

```
PRIMARY KEY(time, id)  -- see below
INDEX(id)              -- Yes, this is sufficient for `id AUTO_INCREMENT`.
```

With those indexes, you could efficiently do

```
WHERE time > ...
ORDER BY time, id
```

which is probably what you really wanted.

Comment: I will check it out but sincerely doubt it might be more efficient from the existing query. The (id = something) condition is needed to avoid slow positioning of the cursor to the nth record. I do not really need ORDER BY time, I care only about ORDER BY id so that I can have as fast as possible paginated export.